# Operator in print statement

Tags: java, string

Example:

```
System.out.println("the investment doubled after "+year+" years.");
```

Can someone please explain why the `int` variable `year` is inside quotations and pluses?

Comment: It isn't inside quotes, it's *outside* quotes.

Comment: I think the int variable is 'year' not 'years'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding some spacing around the operators may make this statement clearer:

```
System.out.println("the investment doubled after " + year + " years.");
```

This statement prints the result of a concatination of three strings, achieved by the two `+` operators:

1. `"the investment doubled after "`
2. The implicit conversion of the `int` variable `year` to a string
3. `" years."`

Comment: Why can I not leave the pluses out and just have "...after" year "years.");

Comment: @mac23 because Java doesn't work that way. If the pluses bother you, uou could use a format string instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is like this. And `+` is used for `String` concatenation. In this `year` is converted into `String` from `int` implicitly.

```
"the investment doubled after " + year + " years."
 ^-------inside quotes-------^            ^-----^Inside quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using the public void println(String x); method. Which means the integer will concatenated to the string when you append the years to the string, that is the reason we are using the + operator.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable year is not inside quotes, it's actually outside of quotes. It is in between of + sign because you are concatenating it.